# How does F/A-18 autotrack work?

Tags: avionics, feature-identification, fa-18

This is about the alleged "UFO" video. However, I'm not interested in speculation about what exactly the aircraft being tracked in the video is.

What is "autotrack" in an F/A-18 Super Hornet? Does it involve tracking by the radar, infrared, or digital interpretation of the video stream by a computer?

I've provided a link to the video. This shows the aircraft (the alleged "UFO") being "tracked" by what the pilot claims to be "autotrack":

As a bonus question, what is the other pilot asking about? He asks "Did you box a moving target?", what does it mean to "box" a moving target? Does it refer to radar tracking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autotrack means the FLIR (Forward Looking InfraRed) sensor attempts to track whatever object falls inside the tracking area. It means whatever the pilot was trying to keep up with was producing emissions in the infrared (heat) and the system was automatically tracking it.

Boxing a moving target is having the tracking system detect and track a target you have selected. In this case, the other pilot was asking if he had selected the target manually (boxing) or if the system detected and autotracked the target on its own.

Comment: Thanks. Although from this explanation it seems like boxing the target is exactly what the pilot in the video did.

Comment: Well, what the pilot did was maneuver the aircraft to allow the targeting computer to use its sensors to present him with a "boxed" target display. A very long time ago i was part of the team at Hughes Aircraft Company that developed the F-14 Tomcat RIO display (back seater). That box was amazing. It could track 12 targets at a time, from acquisition to destruction, and inside all it had was two Intel 8088 CPU's, the same as the very first IBM-PC. And *no* math coprocessor!

Comment: I see, thanks. The F-14 RIO has two 8088's that are programmable, when developing software for it? I wasn't aware the 8088's were found in SMP configurations. Very interesting.

Comment: 8088's are general purpose CPU's, you write the code, they just run it. Like I said, it was an amazing box.

Comment: I have experience writing x86 assembly, although not for the 8088, but dealing with two physical CPUs in an SMP system typically requires an APIC or similar to handle inter-process interrupts and similar issues that are needed to manage an SMP system. I'm just surprised that such a simple CPU as the 8088 had a working SMP ecosystem with all the required hardware and software support required to have two parallel execution threads to do useful work --- not to mention in an F-14!

Comment: All I can tell you is what I posted. I can't get into any further details of the internals... other than it was mostly written in PL/M... and frankly, that was 36 years ago, just a little while after I completed my stint with the Marines. A lot of neurons have been sacrificed to the Jack Daniels' god since then, so my recollection is not so hot. I *can* tell you that I tried to solve their math coprocessor problem (all their math was table driven) by suggesting the use of the NEC V20 CPU. But that did not fly because it wasn't manufactured in the US.

Comment: I would be surprised if the two 8088's were used in an SMP architecture. More likely would be one handles the sensor data and passes that data to the other chip to perform the tracking.

Comment: @selectstriker2 Agreed.

Comment: @JuanJimenez cool! And thanks for serving!